# PHP while(variable=mysql_fetch_assoc) - explanation

Tags: php, syntax, while-loop

I have been working with C# so this is quite strange for me:

```
    while($variable=mysql_fetch_assoc)

{   $X=$variable['A'];
    $Y=$variable['B'];  
}
```

**If it is like an ordinary loop, then X,Y will be reset with every loop, right?**

I have not been able to look up in PHP manual how it works. I guess that in each loop it advances to next element of assoc.array. But what is this generally called in PHP? I am just not used to see '=' in loop condition.

Comment: It's just a $variable to be reset with every loop.

Comment: It's just called an assignment. The assignment happens to return the value that was last assigned.

Comment: In PHP (and most other scripting languages), variable assignment can be considered to be an implicit function call, where the return value is what you were assigning: `$a = ($b = 7)` will assign '7' to $b AND to $a.

Answer (score 3):

Assignment in PHP is an expression that returns the value that was assigned. If a row was retrieved then the result will be non-false, which will allow the loop to continue.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` (and its related functions) advance `$result`'s internal pointer every time it gets called. So `$variable` will be assigned a new row array every time the `while` condition is checked. After the last row is returned, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` can't advance the internal pointer anymore, so the next attempt to call it will return `false`. Once `$variable` becomes false, the condition is no longer satisfied and the loop exits.

In PHP (also JavaScript et al), a condition is true as long as it doesn't evaluate to either zero, an empty string, `NULL` or `false`. It doesn't have to evaluate to a boolean value. That's why such a loop works.

**EDIT:**

> **If it is like an ordinary loop, then X,Y will be reset with every loop, right?**

Yes, they'll be reassigned with the new values from each new row that is fetched.

Comment: Also the solution is just to declare them out of the while loop?

Comment: Depends on what you need them for. I can't tell much from your code.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps looking at the code like this would be useful:

```
while (($variable = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) == true) {
  // loops until the fetch function returns false (no more rows)
  // $variable will have be an associative array containing the 'next' row from the recordset in $result
}
```

It's a shorthand way of doing this:

```
$variable = mysql_fetch_assoc();
while ($variable) {
  // loop

  $variable = mysql_fetch_assoc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means something like "until you can `mysql_fetch_assoc()` an element from the variable you pass to that function, then do the body of the while.

It returns an array if it can find an element, `FALSE` otherwise, so you can exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's just short form of this code:

```
$variable = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
while($variable != FALSE) {
  // do something
  $variable = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
}
```